# Angular Material & CSS (Chrome): why overflow:scrolling causes content overlap?

Tags: css

I have a container of fixed height (same problem with max-height) and overflow-y: scroll.

I add dinamically few divs inside it.

When the container is completely filled in, it starts to scroll but the dics inside it overlap, like the new added divs couldn't fit in the scrollable container.

While the container and the divs are made of pure CSS and HTML (without using Angular Material's directives and not even paddings which occasionally cause problems), I noticed that some global style applies.

Any clue?
Two images are attached to show the problem, the first one without overlap (the container div of max-height: 350px is not yet full), the other where overlapping starts occuring and gets worse the more I add content.

[image]
[image]

I noticed that the issue occurs even without overflow-y: scroll.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show your problem? It is very difficult to help without knowing what css is applied to your code.

Comment: We need the HTML and CSS in the question so that the problem can be re-created.

Comment: you are absolutely right.
However I solved.
It was about Angular Material classes.
too complex to replicate though